# QGIS expression to set all attributes in the blob field to true

Tags: qgis-3, expression

I would like to use an expression to set the blob field true for all attributes.

How do I do this?

[image]

> "aufteilen"  =  'true' or "aufteilen" = 1

doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The expression will evaluate `'true'` as a string/literal, not a boolean value. You must use `true` instead.

Blank/Null/false values:
[image: false]

Expression to evaluate all as true:
[image]

Expression run, values updated:
[image]

Layer saved, no longer editing:
[image]